# DateTime.ToLongDateString with different culture

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert a date(DateTime) to a string in a long format with the culture I need?

But the method(DateTime.ToLongDateString()) of converting date to long format string does not accept culture.

Long date string:  "Wednesday, May 16, 2001"

In short, you can do this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
date.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ToLongDateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolongdatestring?view=net-6.0) is using the format info's [`LongDatePattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern?view=net-7.0), which is `"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"`.

So you can use:

```
date.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Or simpler, use the [long date ("D") format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#LongDate) `"D"`:

```
date.ToString("D", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Result: `Thursday, October 27, 2022`